# calling globals in Javascript: Declared variables vs native objects

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

i have declared global variable as follows:

```
var glob = "smiley";
```

However i want to call it from inner scope of 3 functions. Like this:

```
// Global is finally found!
(function(){
    // glob not found, then browser searches upwards
    (function(){
        // glob not found, then browser searches upwards
        (function(){
            var joe = glob;
            var win = window;
        })();
    })();
})();
```

Since window is a javascript keyword, it is taken from global scope directly, without searching outer scopes? And is there any efficient way how to call a global variable in Javascript directly? Without searching in all previous scopes?

Comment: No, `window` is not a keyword. It's just a variable like all others.

Comment: What's the problem with searching in outer scopes? It's not like you have to do it by hand with pen and paper. You should be able to get it with `window.glob` btw, or `win.glob`in your example.

Comment: Implementations don't necessarily perform a sequential search through each execution context looking for variables. They may create an index of variables available to a certain scope when creating each context. Or they might have other, more efficient ways of looking up the scope chain.

Comment: @Bergi—are you sure that's a duplicate?

Comment: @RobG Just what i was thinking..

Comment: @RobG: No, "*What does this pattern do?*" and "*How to solve this problem?*" are not exactly the same question, but when the pattern solves the problem (canonically) closing seemed fine to me. Feel free to reopen and answer instead.

Comment: initialize to `window.glob = 'smiley';` I'd be careful with using the term **call** when you are trying to reference a variable.